# Looking for a quality pitch shift plugin for Logic 9

Tags: pitch-shifting, plugin, logic, 192k

I'd love to get some high quality pitch shifting plug that can be automated and sounds really good...any tips? I'd love to put my 192k recordings to a good use :-)

Answer (score 2):

Izotope Radius, specifically made for Logic. One of the best sounding algorithms in my experience.

EDIT: If you are looking at varispeed, Logic's tool does the job - using classic mode

Comment: what do you mean by classic mode?

Comment: @Bartosz In the Time & Pitch Machine (select Region > Sample Editor > Factory > Time & Pitch Machine) select 'Classic' under the 'Mode' menu. 

Answer (score 0):

Serato Pitch n Time Pro is considered a very good choice